# Changing the View Position of item in RecyclerView on scroll in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I am using below adapter for recyclerview in chat application but on scrolling I automatically position changed. I used getItemViewType() I think that this provide problem.

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<Message> messageList;
private int SELF = 7861212;

public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messages) {
    messageList = messages;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View mview = null;

    if (viewType == SELF) {
        mview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_user2_item, parent, false);
    } else {
        mview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_user1_item, parent, false);

    }

    return new MyViewHolder(mview);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Message message = messageList.get(position);

    holder.message_text.setText(message.getText());
    holder.chat_company_reply_author.setText(message.getName());


    if (message.isfile()) {
        if (message.getMessageStatus() != null && message.getMessageStatus() == Status.DELIVERED) {
            holder.rl_file.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.progress_bar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            try {
                holder.user_reply_status.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_double_tick));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        if (message.getFiletype() != null) {
            holder.rl_file.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        if (message.getMessageStatus() != null && message.getMessageStatus() == Status.DELIVERED) {
            try {
                holder.user_reply_status.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_double_tick));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    try {
        Picasso.with(context).
                load(Constant.BASE_URL_FORDOWNLOD + "" + message.getFileurl()).
                placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                into(holder.img_chat);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Message message = messageList.get(position);
    if (message.getUserType() == UserType.SELF) {
        return SELF;
    }
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messageList.size();
}

public void add(Message message, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    messageList.add(message);
    notifyItemInserted(messageList.size() - 1);
}

public void mesage_status(int issent, int position) {
    Message message = messageList.get(position);
    if (issent == 1) {
        message.setMessageStatus(Status.SENT);
    }
    if (issent == 2) {
        message.setMessageStatus(Status.DELIVERED);
    }
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView chat_company_reply_author, message_text, time_text;
    public ImageView img_chat, user_reply_status;
    public RelativeLayout rl_file;
    public ProgressBar progress_bar1;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        img_chat = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_chat);
        user_reply_status = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_reply_status);
        chat_company_reply_author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_company_reply_author);
        message_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        time_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_text);
        rl_file = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_file);
        progress_bar1 = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar1);
    }

    public void setvalue(Message message, int position) {

        message_text.setText(message.getText());
        chat_company_reply_author.setText(message.getName());


        if (message.isfile()) {
            if (message.getMessageStatus() != null && message.getMessageStatus() == Status.DELIVERED) {
                rl_file.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progress_bar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                try {
                    user_reply_status.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_double_tick));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            if (message.getFiletype() != null) {
                rl_file.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        } else {
            if (message.getMessageStatus() != null && message.getMessageStatus() == Status.DELIVERED) {
                try {
                    user_reply_status.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_double_tick));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        try {
            Picasso.with(context).
                    load(Constant.BASE_URL_FORDOWNLOD + "" + message.getFileurl()).
                    placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).
                    into(img_chat);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

[chat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8lal.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: Please do not add in urgent begging again. If you do, I will ask a moderator to look at your post. Not only is it necessary for you to know volunteers will not take your urgent instructions, but since you have solved it, it is clearly not important at all to insist on your original version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got my problem is when i use`holder.rl_file.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`  it should be `holder.rl_file.setVisibility(View.GONE);`  in false condition.